# Need help about generating graphs/charts and reports

Tags: jasper-reports, jfreechart

I am currently working on a system which handles the management by business objectives of an organization.I need to generate reports and also the graphical representation of certain things like employee performance in particular year,company growth etc.So I studied certain tools/APIs for that.
Now my question is can I use jasperreports for reporting part of the system and jfreechart for chart/graphical part of system and then integrate it ? or is there any another open source tool/API available for that ? 
plz help.
Thanks in advance...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get some idea of the versatility of [JFreeChart](http://www.jfree.org/jfreechart/samples.html) from the [demo](http://www.jfree.org/jfreechart/samples.html) and [examples](http://www.jfree.org/jfreechart/api/javadoc/org/jfree/chart/demo/package-summary.html). I haven't used [JasperReports](http://jasperforge.org/projects/jasperreports).

Answer (score 0):

You can use google visualization charts, high charts, jplot.

[Google Visualization](http://code.google.com/apis/chart/interactive/docs/index.html)

[High Charts](http://www.highcharts.com/)

[Jqplot](http://www.jqplot.com/) - Uses jquery

Comment: Thanks for your reply.But Google Visualization is used only when net connection is there and it will not be the case in my system.

Comment: Probably u can use jqplot.. by downloading the plugin